# Serving static files in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a simple web application that fetches some data from an API and shows it to the user.

Currently I have two routes, '/' and '/tables/:id'. Both of which render an ejs. I also have the static folder set as such:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

When I try going to the tables/:id route, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not 
Found) table.js
```

table.js is a js file that is linked in the ejs rendered by the route. It is inside a directory called js, which is inside the public directory which ive set as static in my server code.

And on the server side, I get the following log:

```
GET /table/js/table.js 404 2.468 ms - 156
```

So for some reason the server tries to fetch the js file from public/table/js instead of from public/js, the latter being what I thought it would do.

So after some searching I added the following to my code and it started working fine:

```
app.use('/table', express.static('public'));
```

Since I do not know express all to well, and I didnt find any solution in their documentation, I am wondering if there is a way to server all static files for all routes from public without having to set static for each individual subroot?

Comment: In your HTML, are you using `<script src='table.js'>`? If so, have you tried `<script src='/table.js'>`

Comment: I have the file in a js folder in public and my src is '/js/table.js'